# Uso de mayúsculas

Tags: ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

Se deben poner en mayúsculas las primeras letras de cada palabra en los diferentes sistemas de medición del tiempo, como: Tiempo Universal Absoluto,  Tiempo Atómico Universal, etc?
Y los capítulos de novelas, pueden ir en mayúsculas?

Answer (score -2):

En la RAE, encontramos al respecto lo siguiente al respecto de la utilización de mayúsculas en determinados ámbitos, ya que en la pregunta no se especifica en que casos ese texto será utilizado;

*mayúsculas. La escritura normal utiliza habitualmente las letras minúsculas, si bien, por distintos motivos, pueden escribirse enteramente con mayúsculas palabras*...

> 4.24. Los sustantivos y adjetivos q**ue forman el nombre de disciplinas científicas**, cuando nos referimos a ellas como materias de estudio, y
> especialmente en contextos académicos (nombres de asignaturas,
> cátedras, facultades, etc.) o curriculares: Soy licenciado en
> Biología; Me he matriculado en Arquitectura; El profesor de Cálculo
> Numérico es extraordinario. Fuera de los contextos antes señalados, se
> utiliza la minúscula...
>
> 4.26. Los nombres de edades y épocas históricas, **cómputos cronológicos**, acontecimientos históricos y movimientos religiosos,
> políticos o culturales: la Edad de los Metales, la Antigüedad, la Edad
> Media, la Hégira, el Cisma de Occidente, la Contrarreforma, la Primera
> Guerra Mundial, la Revolución de los Claveles, el Renacimiento.
> Igualmente se escriben con mayúscula los sustantivos que dan nombre a
> eras y períodos geológicos: Cuaternario, Mioceno, Pleistoceno,
> Jurásico. El adjetivo especificador que acompaña, en estos casos, a
> los sustantivos Revolución e Imperio se escribe con minúscula: la
> Revolución francesa, el Imperio romano.
>
> 4.32. En **textos de carácter publicitario, propagandístico o similar**, es frecuente la aparición de mayúsculas no justificadas desde el punto
> de vista ortográfico, así como el fenómeno inverso, esto es, la
> aparición de minúsculas donde las normas prescriben la mayúscula.
> **Estos usos expresivos o estilísticos, cuya finalidad es llamar la
> atención del receptor para asegurar así la eficacia del mensaje, no
> deben extenderse, en ningún caso, a otro tipo de escritos.**
>
> 4.33. También es habitual que en **textos pertenecientes a ámbitos particulares** se escriban con mayúscula las palabras que designan
> conceptos de especial relevancia dentro de esos ámbitos. Así, por
> ejemplo, es normal ver escritos con mayúscula, en textos religiosos,
> palabras como Sacramento, Bautismo, Misa; o, en textos militares, las
> palabras Bandera o Patria. Estas mayúsculas, que no deben extenderse a
> la lengua general, obedecen únicamente a razones expresivas o de
> respeto.

https://www.rae.es/dpd/may%C3%BAsculas

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta tan detallada, el contexto para mis dos preguntas es una novela de ciencia ficción.

Comment: Imagino que si escribes, Tiempo Universal Absoluto (TUA), Tiempo Atómico Universal (TAU)... y añades detrás el acrónimo como si fueran valores o expresiones de magnitudes, no creo que exista ningún problema.  Gracias.

Comment: O si los sustantivos y adjetivos que forman el nombre, (Tiempo Universal Absoluto, Tiempo Atómico Universal... ) son consideradas en tu libro disciplinas científicas existentes dentro de esa ficción.

Comment: Cuál es la parte de la respuesta que hace referencia a Tiempo Universal Absoluto y Tiempo Atómico Universal?

Comment: Para no perderse con casos particulares, la idea general es que si el concepto lo puedes asimilar a un nombre propio (único), puede estar con  mayúsculas, pero si lo dudas, casi seguro que debe ir con minúsculas. Se puede escribir «en la razón»  o «en La Razón» según te refieras un motivo (como otro cualquiera, común)  o a un diario en particular  (nombre único, propio) ¿El TAU es un tiempo común, como el tiempo para comer o pensar, o es algo único? Pues  ...  ¿Cúantos universos hay? `:-)`